# How to generate react native android apk for production?

Tags: react-native

I am to trying to generate android apk for react native .
Going through document given at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content

1)Generated the keystore 
2) Setting up gradle variables
3)Adding signing config to your app's gradle config #
4) Generated signed apk for releasse through android studio (build --> genrate signed apk)

I am having react .gradle in my project.
But running this apk gives error java.lang.RuntimeException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __fbBatchedBridge (:1)

Answer (score 1):

It seem's that you are still runing the dev's mod app. Are you sure that you followed all the todo for "generating a signed APK" ???

-`generate keytool`

-`Place the my-release-key.keystore file under the android/app`

-`Edit the file ~/.gradle/gradle.properties with correct values.`

-`Edit the file android/app/build.gradle and add release{}' part.`

-`And cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`

Make sure to launch the correct apk in `android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk"`